# MPMoviePlayerController unmutes hardware mute in AVAudioPlayer

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, mpmovieplayercontroller, avaudioplayer

I've set my phone to muted state by switching vibrate/sound hardware button. In whole application some background music is playing unless the device is in muted state. So in this case, my music is playing but muted. Now in some point I want to present video (which is without sound but this shouldn't matter), however the video in MPMoviePlayerController turns music from AVAudioPlayer on even though the device is is 'muted' state. The AVAudioPlayer continues to play loudly even when i quit MPMoviePlayerController.

Some code samples, but i doubt it will help:

```
// movie without sound
[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategorySoloAmbient error:nil];
NSURL *movieURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"myVideo" ofType:@"mp4"]];
_moviePlayerController = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:movieURL];
[_scrollView addSubview:_moviePlayerController.view];
[_moviePlayerController prepareToPlay];
[_moviePlayerController play];

// music
_audioPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url error:&error];
[_audioPlayer prepareToPlay];
[_audioPlayer play];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To fix this, I had to rewrite the code but instead of using `MPMoviePlayerController` I've used `AVPlayer`. Everything works like a charm now.